# Unauthorized interaction with google calendar API v3

Tags: python, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I'm in the same situation as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112939/login-required-401-unauthorized-message-when-calling-the-v3-google-calendar-ap) (only that my problem is with python): I'm trying to retrieve data using a service account (using [this example](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/service_account/tasks.py) and after reading [this blog entry](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.ar/2011/12/calendar-api-v3-2-legged-oauth-java.html) since my application is a google app) but I get hit with a **login required** error and I cannot understand why.

Let me represent it with a whole example:

```
In [1]: import httplib2                                                          
In [2]: from apiclient.discovery import build                                   
In [3]: from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials            
In [4]: f = open('abd45679ffg32343-privatekey.p12', 'rb')
In [5]: key = f.read()                                                          
In [6]: f.close()                                                               
In [7]: credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(                            
        '2127313127654990@developer.gserviceaccount.com', key,                     
        scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',                      
               'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'])            
In [8]: http = httplib2.Http()                                                  
In [9]: http = credentials.authorize(http)                                      
In [10]: service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http,       
   ....:         developerKey='XcddfRgtyt676grggtT')        
2012-05-14 18:24:35,170 INFO  [root][MainThread] URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest                                                              
2012-05-14 18:24:35,170 INFO  [oauth2client.client][MainThread] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
2012-05-14 18:24:35,179 INFO  [oauth2client.client][MainThread] Refresing access_token
In [11]: service.calendarList().list().execute()                                
2012-05-14 18:25:00,418 INFO  [root][MainThread] URL being requested https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?alt=json&key=XcddfRgtyt676grggtT          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------     
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)     
/home/mariano/Code/Kalendar/rest/kalendar/<ipython-input-12-0cb769615d74> in <module>()
----> 1 service.calendarList().list().execute()                                 
/home/mariano/Code/Kalendar/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.0beta8-py2.7.egg/apiclient/http.pyc in execute(self, http)                                     
387                                                                         
388       if resp.status >= 300:                                            
--> 389         raise HttpError(resp, content, self.uri)                        
390     return self.postproc(resp, content)                                 
391                                                                         
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?alt=json&key=XcddfRgtyt676grggtT returned "The user must be signed up for Google Calendar.">
```

Any pointers about why is this happening and how to solve it would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Maybe you should not include all credentials, this is a public facing website after all...

Comment: They are all fake, don't worry. Thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think service accounts are available for Calendar API. The service account has no calendar of its own.

Comment: That could explain it. Let me ask in the issue tracker

Comment: You were right: http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com.ar/2012/03/service-accounts-have-arrived.html

Comment: I have successfully gotten it to work previously. Schillingt has shown this answer to be false.

Comment: This is old information. Service accounts are indeed available for the Calendar API (tested with v3 at least).

Answer (score 1):

Service Accounts are available and work with Calendar API for me.

You need to change your following statement:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('2127313127654990@developer.gserviceaccount.com', key, scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'])
```

to

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('2127313127654990@developer.gserviceaccount.com', key, scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'], prn='requestor@domain.com')
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing.  If the email address of the calendar owner is "john.doe@gmail.com", is that what I would enter in the "prn" field?  Do you know if the calendar has to be configured in any way (like making it public)?  I keep getting an "access denied" error that says "Error refreshing the OAuth2 token" (I'm using the PHP library).  My calendar is set to public.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The service accounts do work with the Calendar API. You have to also grant access on your domain management as well.

Do as user1260486 and btspierre said, and add the `"prn=requestor@domain.com"` to the constructor for `SignedJWTAssertionCredentials`.

Then go to your domain management and add your `client_id` access to the API.

Here's a [walkthrough](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162106) about it.
For the scope specify `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"`