# auth with google calendar api v3

Tags: python, calendar

from this guy's ask: [Unauthorized interaction with google calendar API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591849/unauthorized-interaction-with-google-calendar-api-v3)

I knew that, google calendar cann't work with service_account.

the point is, I need to write a script/python which run in my server, and this script fetch my calendar data from google calendar

but, how can i auth to google?  not web application, not installed_app, just a script

Thanks.

Comment: I have provided an answer, but after you have read through those links maybe you can refine your question? It's a bit broad.

Answer (score 0):

These are the instructions for getting [API access for a Google Calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp).

There are detailed instructions for installing the [Google libraries and example code here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate).

Answer (score 0):

Actually google calendar works fine with service account. I use it successfully in php and java. You will need to go to the Google developer console to create a project, and then create the service account for that project, and enable the API access. You will use the service account id and secret key it gave you to do the authorization.