# google service account get key

Tags: java, service, console, private-key

I want to get private key from google api console .

I can do it manually but I  want to do it programmatically in JAVA.

Following references uses the private key file for authentication to google apis.

1) ["Login Required" 401 Unauthorized message when calling the v3 Google Calendar API using a Service Account via OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112939/login-required-401-unauthorized-message-when-calling-the-v3-google-calendar-ap)

2) [Authenticating Google API with a service account with Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827817/authenticating-google-api-with-a-service-account-with-java-api)

Once I'll export private key file from google console , I will use it for authentication as mentioned in above links.

I am using google api version 2.0 with Oauth 2.0 in JAVA.