# 403 Forbidden message when calling the v3 Google Calendar API using a Service Account via OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, http-status-code-403

This is a follow on from my thread about a 401 error when using the Google Calendar API and OAuth2, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112939/login-required-401-unauthorized-message-when-calling-the-v3-google-calendar-ap)

This contains details of the account setup that leads onto my next question, so I wont repeat myself in this thread.

OK, so when when I call the following code to update a Calendar event I get a 403 forbidden error.

```
for (Event event : events.getItems())
{
    event.setSummary("XXX" + event.getSummary());

    Event updatedEvent = calendar.events().update(CALENDAR_ID, event.getId(), event).execute();
}
```

Here is the returned error message:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [ {
        "message" : "Forbidden"
     } ],
    "message" : "Forbidden"
}
```

What have I tried? Well, I have re-read the (rather poor) Google documentation about Service Accounts, re-checked my API Console account settings, tried changing the code that builds the credential (this leads to other errors so is a regression on my previous thread).

In short, nothing works, so is there anything obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solved, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11897793/811108) post.

You have to share the calendar from your Google Calendar account with the Service Account email that is generated in the Google API Console, e.g. *284XXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com*.

I can now update my calendar from my web service.

Comment: hii can u plz tell me how can i share the calendar from google console?i already share this calendar for my android calendar but not getting any solution?still got this error.

Comment: I'm getting error with 403 forbidden. when i shared my calendar it display my email id as owner please how to configure???

Comment: I have the same problem. The solution is: 1) Check all credentials you setup for Calendar.Builder(). 2) Share the calendar with your Service Account and make sure "Make changes to events" is selected in "Permission Settings".

Answer (score 6):

I was also getting the same error even after sharing the calendar as in the Justin's answer. After comparing with another working sample figured out that I have set

```
var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];
```

instead of

```
var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"];
```

Hope this helps anyone who has done a similar mistake and getting this error.

Comment: Hi there! This solution worked for me thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to enable the CalDAV API in the Google API console. It gives a 403 response if disabled.

I know this is an old question, but this might be helpful for someone.

Comment: Good idea to still post. As the API moves on, there are probably new reasons why this error can arise. I can't believe I posted this question seven years ago!

Answer (score 0):

For me, after trying all of the suggested solutions above, nothing worked. I got it to work after looking what scopes they were using in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list).

I was fetching for events, and it seemed that the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` scope wasn't enough.
I had to add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events` as well to my scopes.

Hopefully it can help someone out there!