# Connecting to Google Calendar v3 API with PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am completely lost... All I'm trying to do is get rid of this error message and log into Google API. I've created all the keys and added them to /src/Google/Config.php.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error   calling GET  

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/0qfrti6gst4q8hpl89utm8elno%40grou    p.calendar.google.com?key=AIzaSyAiR_4OsoheCPbd7tU2u3QrqbEW_a2uVCc: (401) Login Required'    

in C:\\Bitnami\\wampstack\\apache2\\htdocs\\yac\\google-api-php-

client\\src\\Google\\Http\\REST.php:79\nStack ...
```

Here's my (most likely) incorrect script:

```
session_start();
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'google-api-php-client/src' );

include_once('google-api-php-client/src');
require_once('google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php');
require_once ('google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("YAC_Calendar");
$client->setDeveloperKey(<MY KEY>);
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->get('0qfrti6gst4q8hpl89utm8elno@group.calendar.google.com');

echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003203/403-forbidden-message-when-calling-the-v3-google-calendar-api-using-a-service-ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to login using Oauth before you can access the calendar.  The only example I have on hand right now is one using Google Analytics API with PHP if you have any switching it over to Calendar let me know I will see if I can get a working example for that.

```
<?php         
require_once 'Google/Client.php';     
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';       
session_start();      
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("{devkey}");  
    $client->setClientId('{clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('{clientsecret}');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://www.daimto.com/Tutorials/PHP/Oauth2.php');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

    //For loging out.
    if ($_GET['logout'] == "1") {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
       }   

    // Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
    if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
        }        

    // Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);    

        // request user accounts
        $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

       foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {
        echo "Account: ",$item['name'], "  " , $item['id'], "<br /> \n";        
        foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WebProperty: ' ,$wp['name'], "  " , $wp['id'], "<br /> \n";    

            $views = $wp->getProfiles();
            if (!is_null($views)) {
                foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {
                //  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;View: ' ,$view['name'], "  " , $view['id'], "<br /> \n";    
                }
            }
        }
    } // closes account summaries

    }
 print "<br><br><br>";
 print "Access from google: " . $_SESSION['token']; 
?>
```

Code from my tutorial [Google Oauth2 php](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/)

Comment: I am pretty sure I saw this in my previous searches but I didn't really know what I was looking for. Thanks for steering me in the right place!

Comment: Do i need to make the OAuth even if the application is only used with my account? isn't it the simple API case? My application is server side and i don't need to ask for the user detail of the user login.. It only affects my google+ account.. sooo, setting the application name and the developer key will suffice? Thanks in advance