# google-oauth calendar returns 401 error

Tags: google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I tried the calendar-appengine-sample on google calendar api java sample and when I used the client_secrets.json for running in localhost it always give me back my calendar list, but when I use the client_secrets.json to be run on google app engine, it give me following error message :

```
ERROR: 401
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

Before it work with the same client_secrets.json, but suddenly it doesn't work. Would anyone be so kindly tell me how to fix this problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had asked this some time back (assuming your using version 3 of the API), and here is a potential [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112939/login-required-401-unauthorized-message-when-calling-the-v3-google-calendar-ap).

If you get a 403 error, which I did after fixing this then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003203/403-forbidden-message-when-calling-the-v3-google-calendar-api-using-a-service-ac).

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your reply. It's still doesn't work for me and in my case I used client_secrets.json as per following code :
http://pastebin.com/uPNLi2Ru